# How do I align text to the left and right at the same time in a listView

Tags: java, android, listview

I just need to have a price next to my products in a listView and they need to be aligned as follows,

- The product name to the left, and;
- The price to the right

This is the code:

```
public ListView lstMenuItems;
public String[] menuItems = {"Fillet On The Bone", "Rump", "Sirloin", "French Cut Pork Cutlets", "Spatchcock Chicken", "Sticky Smoked Paprika Chicken Wings", "Craft Beer Battered Fish", "Butter Chicken", "Pomegranate & Chilli Marinated Lamb Skewer", "Pork Belly Skewer", "Harissa Basted Chicken Skewer"};
public double[] itemPrice = {135, 99, 99, 99, 89, 79, 60, 75, 99, 95, 69};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);
    TitleBar(waiterName);
    GetListViewValue();
    menuItems = AddPad(menuItems, itemPrice);
    MenuList();

}

    public void MenuList() {

    lstMenuItems = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProducts);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.category_list, menuItems);
    lstMenuItems.setAdapter(adapter);

}


public String[] AddPad(String[] menu, double[] price) {
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        menu[i] = String.format("%-60s %s",menu[i], format.format(price[i]));
    }
    return menu;
}
```

The `String.format` class doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to do this?

Please Help

Comment: you should write a custom listview adapter http://stackoverflow.com/a/33774046/5381331

Comment: Never pad by adding spaces in a real app.  That's ok for high school apps when you're just learning, but its sloppy and inexact for a real app.  It isn't even assured to work-  a space isn't always the same width (what if they changed the font size in settings).  The real way to do this is to make a custom layout for your adapter.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? @GabeSechan

Answer (score 1):

Create your custom adapter. In getView you'll be able to customize line you want. You can extend BaseAdapter for it.

Answer (score 0):

you should write a custom `listview` adapter to achieve this:

```
public class myCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductClass> {

    public myCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public myCustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ProductClass> pc) {
        super(context, resource, pc);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row, null);
        }

        ProductClass p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView product_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            TextView product_price = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
            product_name.setText(p.getProductName());
            product_price.setText(p.getCategory().getPrice());

        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

Add a `ListView` to your activity layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ProductListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
</ListView>
```

Create a XML layout and name it `custom_list_row.xml`. This is for `ListView` rows.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
              android:id="@+id/product_name"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="right"/>

 <TextView
              android:id="@+id/product_price"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="left"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And in your activity :

```
ListView ProductListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ProductListView);
List<ProductClass> lst = myProductList();
myCustomAdapter productAdapter = new myCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_list_row, lst);
ProductListView.setAdapter(productAdapter);
```

Note: `lst` is your product list which contains product name and it's price.

**EDIT: Your product class must be look like this**

```
public class ProductClass {
        public String product_name;
        public float price;

        public String getProductName()
        {
            return product_name;
        }
        public String getPrice()
        {
            return String.ValueOf(price);
        }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: How should my ProductClass look like?